# Dúvida com insert no banco Postgres

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, oracle

Estou com uma mensagem de erro, tentei várias opções de não conseguir uma solução.
Será que existe alguma configuração que está faltando?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O campo nome é um array? se for vai chaves nele

Comment: você resolveu o meu problema, eu sempre usei sql server e não tinha ideia que o tipo de campo e bem diferente, eu ajustei o campo do banco e deu certo, eu tinha colocado um campo do tipo array, não sabia que isso era possível

Comment: Todos os campos do postgres tem uma versão em array, na hora criar um veja tem o `char` e o `char[]` por exemplo.

Comment: value a dica, muito grato

Answer (score 1):

O nome parece ser do tipo array, nesse caso é preciso informa a sintaxe correta são necessárias chaves.

```
INSERT INTO empresa (id, nome) VALUES(2, '{teste}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que na hora de criar o campo você tenha usado `Character Varing[]` que é um array de varchars (ou um array de strings dinâmicas). O campo correto, se você quer criar apenas 1 string, é `Character Varing` e no campo length o tamanho máximo da string.

Quanto a sintaxe do insert, se existe mais de um comando na query cada um deles deve terminar com ";". No seu caso:

```
insert into empresa (id,nome) values (2,'teste');
select * from empresa;
```

Mas se forem vários inserts pode-se fazer o seguinte:

```
insert into empresa (id,nome) values (1, 'teste1'), (2, 'teste2'), ..., (n, 'testeN');
```

Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c939/5)

Answer (score 0):

Expressões constantes literais:

```
INSERT INTO empresa ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, '{ testeA, testeB, testeC }'::text[] );
```

Expressões com `ARRAY`:

```
INSERT INTO empresa ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, ARRAY[ 'testeA', 'testeB', 'testeC' ] );
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html